# Is it possible to retrieve the URLs of child lists from the parent list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom, csom, related-list

Is there any way to retrieve the URLs or a least the Names/IDs of all child lists that have lookup columns referencing the parent list in SharePoint. It is easy to find the parent list of a child list by expanding the lookup column with REST but I can't figure out a way to get the child lists of a parent.  It seems like this should be possible since SharePoint has an OOTB WebPart to display related lists.

I know it can be done out of the box, but I need a way to retrieve the child lists with client-side code. This is part of a custom solution and I can't use out of the box web parts.

Comment: Give an example. That will help to understand

Answer (score 0):

We have a workaround solution for your requirement, the lists that has a lookup column in it will definitely be a child list to some parent list in the site. So we may find all the lists in the site that contains lookup column in it.

You may create a console application and include the below code to get the all the lists that has a lookup column.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(“URL”)
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web.Lists);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (List list in web.Lists)
{
    context.Load(list.Fields);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SP.Field field in list.Fields)
    {
        if (field.FieldTypeKind.ToString().Equals("Lookup"))
            Console.WriteLine(list.Title + " has a lookup column: " + field.InternalName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with javascript and the REST api?